# Paid member plugin with some specific features

Tags: plugin-recommendation, membership, members

I was wondering if anyone knew of a paid membership plugin that streamlined the peyment/registration process into a single step.

Ideally there would be a signup page. This page would have the typical fields (email address, possibly a user name and password) as well as the paypal button (only active when all required fields are filled). I want the new user to be able to enter their info, then go straight to paypal to pay, then upon payment confirmation (via IPN) the plugin would create the user ID and send a confirmation link to the email address entered.

The biggest problem I had with the plugins I tried (S2Memeber, Members) was the fact that users had to first create an account, then subsequently purchase a membership. It was causing a lot of confusion, very few users actually went through the whole process without emailing the site for help. Many thought there was a problem when the account creation page had no payment options and emailed for support. I can try to work around it by offering more instructions on the account registration page, but ideally I'd like to consolidate these two steps into a single process.

The plugin doesn't need to manage content restrictions, I can handle that myself. All I want is an automated system for user/payment management that will automatically demote users when there subscription lapses or payment fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Membership plugin from Wpmudev.org should fit your needs:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership/

This is step 2 of the registration process with Membership:
[image: Step 2 of the registration process with Membership]

**EDIT:**
According to comments that membership should give access to certain custom post type i would suggest this:

1. Create a template for that custom post type as
   `single-premium-videos.php` More info:
   https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files
2. Then add a check if the current user is member/has subscription
   More info: http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/check-to-see-if-user-is-member-or-non-member#post-194924

Use `current_user_is_member()` or `current_user_has_subscription()`

```
if(!current_user_is_member()) { 
$location = get_bloginfo('url') . '/non-member-page';
// Redirect non-members to a new url
wp_redirect( $location ); 
exit; 
}
```

Otherwise you can make also an if/else statement where you'll show a different content to members and non-members on these custom post type pages

```
if(!current_user_is_member()) {
  // Content for non-members
} else {
  // Content for members
}
```

Comment: I actually already bought that one but abandoned it because I couldn't find a way to filter by custom post type (which is how I'm seperating paid content and regular content).

Maybe I'll revisit and try to figure out a different method to separate content.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're trying to accomplish? I have some development experience with that.

Comment: My initial plan was to create a custom post type (ie. premium-videos) and then use the membership plugin to control access to all posts of that post type (ie. only paid members can view posts of type premium-videos). I just though it would be slightly more convenient for the people handling the content creation.

Comment: @geoken, I've edited the answer according to your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Paid Memberships Pro handles payment and user creation at the same time. The one difference vs. your specs is that PMPro doesn't wait for IPN verification and assumes the payment will go through and gives the user access immediately.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/

The reason we don't wait for verification is because depending on what payment method the user chose, it could take 5 minutes to 2 days for verification to come back. So we assume PayPal is going to make good.

Depending on the type of content you are selling, this may or may not be acceptable for you.

Also note that PMPro uses PayPal Express, which is different from PayPal standard in that customers have to sign up for a PayPal account at checkout if they don't have one.

Might work for you.

Good luck.